# How do I translate CIL to LLVM IR?

Tags: compilation, llvm, cil

I want to compile C# to LLVM IR. So I think translate compiled CIL to LLVM IR is one way I can try.

There are some tools I can use such as vmkit and mono-llvm.

Is anybody using this tools? Or how can I translate CIL to LLVM?

Answer (score 5):

To get LLVM IR code from CIL you need to use the tool il2bc (other name C# Native) which you can download from http://csnative.codeplex.com/.

You just need to perform some simple steps.

```
Il2Bc.exe <Your DLL>.dll
```

If you want to generate an executable from it, you need to compile the generated .ll file (LLVM IR Code).

For example, you have your "Hello World" app

1. Compile it (it will generate a helloworld.ll file)

   ```
   Il2Bc.exe helloworld.cs /corelib:CoreLib.dll
   ```
2. Generate LLVM IR file for the core library (it will generate corelib.ll file)

   ```
   Il2Bc.exe CoreLib.dll
   ```
3. You need to generate an EXE file (it will generate a .EXE file):

   ```
   llc -filetype=obj -mtriple=i686-w64-mingw32 CoreLib.ll
   llc -filetype=obj -mtriple=i686-w64-mingw32 helloworld.ll
   g++ -o helloworld.exe helloworld.obj CoreLib.obj -lstdc++ -lgc-lib -march=i686 -L .
   ```

Comment: how does this native code handle the garbage collection step ?

Comment: LLVM IR does support garbage collection (the mechanism has to be implemented though), although I'm not entirely sure since when.

Comment: link to codeplex is broken, maybe hosted in github now?

Comment: no, there is no more il2Bc. Only the latest is https://github.com/ASDAlexander77/cs2cpp when C# can be converted to C++

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on your goals. Why do you want to translate C# to LLVM?

VMKit was designed as a framework for building virtual machine implementations. I believe it had some support for the CLR at one point, but that support since stagnated in favor of its JVM implementation. Its purpose is to make building a VM from scratch.

Mono-llvm is a project that replaces the mono JIT backend with an LLVM back end. It's goal is to improve the performance of JITed code on Mono.

If your goal is to use Mono, with better performance, mono-llvm is a good choice.

If you want to build an entire VM from scratch, then VMKit might work.

If you are just looking to implement an ahead-of-time compiler that produces executables with no CLR dependencies, you can just download the LLVM core libraries from:

http://llvm.org/

Basically it would translate the CIL into a textual representation of LLVM IR and then use the LLVM APIs to compile it to native machine code.

I don't know if LLVM will generate object files for you. You may have to generate them yourself, but that's pretty easy. It's basically just stuffing the machine code into a data structure, building up string, section, and symbol tables, and then serializing everything to disk.

Answer (score 4):

I think I understand the question to be that you want to use LLVM IR in the same way that the GCC can compile Java using gcj?

The LLVM had an option to output CIL directly from whatever front end you used (So in theory you could do C/C++ to CIL). The following command options:

```
llc -march=msil
```

would output CIL from (in theory) any supported LLVM Front-End.

Going from C# or CIL to LLVM IR hasn't been done yet (or at least finished). You'd need a C# front-end.

[VMKit](http://vmkit.llvm.org/get_started.html) had some kind of C# front end scaffolding. Support was never feature complete and interest has since faded. They've moved to just supporting Java. You might try their source repository and see if there are any remnants of their early C# work can be reworked into a full C# frontend.

Also note that you can write your own *C# to LLVM IR* compiler in C# (using [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) or whatever) and use [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) to call into LLVM libraries and create LLVM IR. There are some good information out there such as *[Writing Your Own Toy Compiler Using Flex, Bison and LLVM](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/)*.

This area is also getting interesting now that the compiler as a service ([Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compiler_Platform)) project has had its first couple of CTP releases, and Mono has its Mono.CSharp project. Though I think Roslyn is a bit more feature-rich.