# Compile C# → LLVM → ASM.JS?

Tags: .net, llvm, asm.js

From my understanding I can compile C++ to LLVM, then use Emscripten which outputs to JavaScript.

From http://kripken.github.io/mloc_emscripten_talk/#/11:

C/C++ → LLVM → Emscripten → JavaScript

How might I generate asm.js via Emscripten (I believe that's what generates asm.js at the moment), and (ASM_JS=1 as a compile flag) is there anything that takes C# or .NET to translate it to LLVM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to translate msil to llvm li?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054938/how-to-translate-msil-to-llvm-li)

Comment: for what it's worth, this is exactly how Unity 3D gets c# code running in a browser without a plugin when you build a project for WebGL.

Answer (score 2):

Mono supports LLVM as backend. However, it will probably require lots of changes to make it compatible with Emscripten

Answer (score 1):

It seems that for the moment there is not the interest necessary. Perhaps one option would be to use [JSIL](http://jsil.org).

Source: https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/411930995366309888